# Copy/Mirror traffic to WAN interfaces without "iptables tee" support

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, mirroring

I want to copy every outgoing packet to others WAN interfaces but my iptables (v1.2.7) has not TEE target support. I wonder if there is another way (maybe using iproute2 or ebtables) to copy every outgoing packet to an selected interface. I prefer other way than getting xtables-addons because im working with a embedded device (an UClinux distribution) and i would prefer avoid new versions of iptables (I dont know if the syntax remains the same among versions), cross-compiling problems or changing Makefiles.

Answer (score 3):

The [`ROUTE` target from patch-o-matic](http://www.mail-archive.com/netfilter-devel@lists.samba.org/msg01285.html) should compile against your kernel and for the 1.2.7 version of iptables and has a `--tee` target option which should do what you want. This being said, iptables 1.2.7 is [over 11 (!!) years old](http://lists.netfilter.org/pipermail/netfilter-devel/2002-June/008255.html) now, probably so is your kernel version. You *really* should consider using a more recent piece of code - a lot has changed in the meantime.

There also is the libpcap-based [port-mirroring project](http://code.google.com/p/port-mirroring/) originally started for the uClibc-backed OpenWRT. It might compile against your platform as well.

Another possible option is the [`mirred` action to `tc`](http://build.onelab.eu/4.0/onelab/2007.05.30--cvs-rc3-svn-tags/CODEBASE/iproute/doc/actions/mirred-usage) - but given the date of your codebase I doubt that it would be included out-of-the box, so it would be compiling Kernel modules again.

Comment: And OpenWRT, at least, has a reasonably modern kernel and userland, unlike whatever this ancient device is...

Comment: Hi, if there is a different solution i would prefer because i dont want to update `iptables` or `kernel` in my firmware project with `autotools`, it may broke currently development. I consider using `port-mirroring project` but i want I want to copy every outgoing packet (packet wiht ip destination out of LAN) not only one+ selected interfaces.

Comment: @user2119381 there is the netfilter / Kernel module approach or libpcap - choose your own adventure. Libpcap is expected to be a bit of a strain on your resources, but would not need kernel-level adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

In case the "TEE" target is not working, you can install a third party "port mirroring" program.

It's based on libpcap: http://code.google.com/p/port-mirroring/